# Copy a file without removing the destination capabilities

Tags: linux, linux-capabilities

I have a binary `foo`, generated from C++ code, which has special capabilities set on it with:

```
sudo setcap cap_sys_rawio=ep ./foo
```

Now I want to build another version of this binary, and the output of the build (the new binary) goes into a file named `bar`. Evidently, `bar` will not have the same capabilities as `foo`. I would like to copy the content of `bar` over `foo`, so that `foo` represents the new binary, but without removing the capabilities.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/92703/523336) indicates that modifying the file does not affect the capabilities, but when I try with `cp` (which uses `open(..., O_TRUNC)` under the covers) the capabilities are removed.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Are you using any of the `cp` options that copy attributes, such as `-a` or `--preserve=xattr`? These will replace foo's capabilities with bar's.

Comment: But they don't want to replace `foo`'s capabilities with `bar`; they want to preserve `foo`'s capabilities, and just replace the *content* of `foo` with the content of `bar`.

Comment: @Barmar - no, I am not using any special options.

Comment: @Barmar - you are mistaken about the scope of SO. It is not just about programming itself. It is also about "software tools commonly used by programmers". I think we can assume a question about Linux capabilities on a program that I wrote and built and needs these special capabilities is totally on-topic here, as are many build related questions. I agree though at it would _also_ be on topic on those other sites: question applicability is not mutually exclusive on the SE network.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. The comment on the answer you linked to is incorrect; replacing the contents of `foo` will cause the capabilities to be removed from `foo`, as explained by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283366/linux-file-capabilities-are-lost-when-i-modify-the-file-is-this-expected-behavi/283408#283408).

You can test this using the following trivial C program (save this as `editfoo.c`):

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int fd = open("foo", O_WRONLY);
    write(fd, "bar", 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Then:

```
$ gcc editfoo.c -o editfoo

$ echo "foo" > foo

$ sudo setcap cap_sys_rawio=ep foo

$ cat foo
foo

$ getcap foo
foo = cap_sys_rawio+ep

$ ./editfoo

$ cat foo
bar

$ getcap foo
```

Comment: Thanks. I also did a similar test and came to the same conclusion. I guess it makes sense since if you could modify the binary it would seem to be a giant security whole, essentially giving the user full cap access since they could update the binary to do anything they needed done with full caps.